# Error 500 Entity Framework API Rest in Azure, not in local

Tags: entity-framework, rest

I have develope a simple API Rest in C# to obtain a list of users. This WS works fine in local but when upload to Azure and query it´s getting to me a 500 error.  In azure access by the next link:

https://garbanzooapirest.azurewebsites.net/API/Users

I try to enable the logs but nothing there.

I have also link debug to Azure instance and don´t get any error but don´t arrive to my get methos. It`s arrive to contructor into MyAppContext.cs class to get the context, and after that goes to dispose methos in  the controler.

I suppose there is a problem with my db conection on web.config or in Azure. The problem is i review it and its looks fine.

When debug, This is the first match (MyAppApiRestContext.cs):

```
    public myAppApiRestContext() : base("name=MyAppApiRestContext")
    {
    }
```

After this stop degug goes to UserController.cs:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

This is my web config in azure:

User, password and url are correct.

I hope to get the same answer than in local, the list of users but i get a 500 error.

My subscription to azure is a pay by use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: web.config in azure:

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyAppApiRestContext" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:myappirestdbserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyAppApiRest_db;User Id=MyApp@myappapirestdbserver;Password=XXXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: I forgot to said i have also configure in App Service a Configuration the same connection String name with the same values.

Answer (score 0):

After a week problem is solve. I just delete tables (all my tables and migration table) in Data base, publish the solution again and then EF recreate the DB and works again! is Magic! Not really, DB and Server deployment wasn´t syncronize....

Is a good idea enable automatic migrations to avoid this kind of errors

Thanks